# isset($string["toto"]) returns false or true function of php version

Tags: php, arrays, string

In my client company, I found a piece of code very strange... I don't understand what the developer wanted to do. And I don't understand PHP logic.

```
var_dump($string["toto"]);
if(isset($string["toto"])) {
  return TRUE;
}
else{
  return FALSE;
}
```

$string is a string, like "house".
var_dump($string["toto"]) returns h, because toto is not an integer, so it's considered as a 0, so it returns the first letter of house.

Then,

In PHP 5.3, `isset($string["toto"])` returns true

In PHP 5.5, `isset($string["toto"])` returns false

Does somebody know why? Something changed in PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5 concerning strings used as characters arrays?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please [RTM](http://php.net/isset):

> ### Changelog
>
> 5.4.0 Checking non-numeric offsets of strings now returns `FALSE`.

I.e., it's an error to try to access a string offset with a string index to begin with. This is now correctly being treated as an error/non-existent index.